# c# sql connection through internet

Tags: c#, sql

I was wondering if can I connect to sql database from another computer without installing sql server (is this possible). I am creating a c# wpf program that would get and insert data in sql database that is placed in my PC, in all computers where this program is installed using internet. Should I use in connection string my internet IP, or what, because I’m confused?

My connection string

```
    String connString = @"Network Library=dbmssocn;
                 Network Address=127.0.0.1,1433;
                 Integrated security=SSPI;
                 Initial Catalog=db";
```

Also i forgot to say that i'm new in programing area, and i want to connect to sql database through lan connection

Comment: Have you tried it yet?

Comment: yes, now i will post my connection. also i forget to mention that not to connect just in lan connection, but beyond lan

Comment: You can do this with a System.Data.SqlClient

Comment: SQL is just the query language - but what **concrete RDBMS** are you talking about? Please tag question with a db system, like `oracle`, `postgresql`, `db2`, `sql-server` or whatever else you might be using!

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that your remote database (on your other computer) accepts remote connections, you can accomplish this via a traditional ADO.NET connection or you could use an ORM like Entity Framework to handle the connection.

You can see an example below that takes advantage of the [`SqlConnection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx) class which does exactly what it's name implies :

```
using(var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String"))
{
      var query = "Your Query";
      using(var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query,sqlConnection))
      {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            // Execute your query here using sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            // or some other execution method
      }
}
```

You would just need to [ensure that your actual connection string to target your remote database is correct](http://www.connectionstrings.com/).

Comment: `Assuming that your remote database (on your other computer) accepts remote connections` It's worth mentioning port forwarding will be needed. And besides that; SQL-connection over internet isn't really a good idea.

Comment: I didn't mean want to imply that this should be the direct approach. I just wanted to indicate how an application could connect with a SQL Database (be it through an API or otherwise). Using a Web API as Jacob recommended is obviously a much safer approach that directly exposing it.

Comment: i don't want to  host database in any server, but to keep in my pc, but when i'am working with the aplication in other pc, the data should be stored in my pc/sql database througth internet

Comment: We likely need a bit more details on the type of database/environment you are using and exactly what you are trying to accomplish. By default if you are developing using Visual Studio, you could use a SQL Server Express LocalDB for doing development locally. These databases however do not support remote connections, so you wouldn't be able to access it outside of your own PC. If you install SQL Server, you could create a non-local database and enable remote connections and access it remotely (assuming you are developing on it), otherwise you could create an API and expose the data that way

Comment: Rion williams, you mention in answer to use a query what query should i use there

Comment: The query mentioned would be whatever you needed to actually query from the database (e.g. `SELECT * FROM YourTable`, `UPDATE YourTable SET Foo = 42`, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible. You could use ADO.NET or Entity Framework to accomplish this goal. However, I would recommend setting up a web api on the sever you have hosting the database, which you could call to get/post data. I personally wouldn't hard code any connection strings in the program you plan to deploy to end user workstations. Just call the web api and let your web api talk to the database.

Comment: Although this doesn't really answers the question, I think this is a better way to accomplish OP's goal than the proposed SQL-connection over internet.

Comment: I have to concur on this one.  My boss where I started working is a SQL pro.  Knows nothing about application development.  Great guy though.  I had to show him the reasons to put his SQL server (if he exposes it to the internet) behind an API.  Limiting attack surface for hackers as well as adding identity with a cert and encryption is one of the many reasons to do this.